# Behavior of sizeof on variable length arrays (C only)

Tags: c, sizeof

My question is how exactly `sizeof()` behaves when passed argument is a <strike>dynamic array</strike> variable length array.

Let's consider an example:

```
int fun(int num_of_chars)
{
    char name_arr[num_of_chars] = {0};

    /* Do something*/

    return sizeof(name_arr);
}
```

In this example it is obvious that return value is not a compile time constant. Because the size depends on run time value of `num_of_chars`.

A quote from C99 standard (6.5.3.4):

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>       expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the 
>       type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a 
>       variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is 
>       not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

What I can understand from [....the operand is evaluated....] is that when the argument passed for `sizeof()` is a <strike>dynamic array</strike> variable length array, **`sizeof()` 'behaves like' a function and not as an operator**.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: `sizeof()` is still an operator; it just no longer generates a compile-time constant when the argument is a variable length array.

Comment: does your code compile? I get a `variable-sized object may not be initialized` error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It still behaves as an operator. Cast is also operator and also evaluates it's argument and so does `*` or `&` . Being an operator is a syntactic category. That does not change.

The important distinction is that it behaves as **expression** while in other cases it behaves as **constant**.

---

Update: I commented below that I don't see why the evaluation makes difference, but now I realized there are *two* ways you can write sizeof with variable length array. Either you can pass variable declared as variable lenght array:

```
int a[x];
sizeof(a)
```

in which case evaluating `a` indeed makes no difference. But you can also use a *type* as the argument, which would be

```
sizeof(int[x])
```

and in this case the result is `x * sizeof(int)` and `x` must be evaluated. Which I suppose is why the specification mentions it.

Comment: "and also evaluates it's argument" - no, it doesn't. The expression passed to `sizeof()` is not evaluated.

Comment: @H2CO3: Please, read the question. It quotes standard saying the operand is evaluated if it is a variable length array. That said the only expression of variable length array type in C99 is so declared variable and evaluating that has no observable effect, so I am not sure why the distinction is made (C++ is another matter, but even C++11 does not include this feature).

Comment: @H2CO3: In fact I now realized that when you pass a variable length array _type_ to `sizeof`, the expression is evaluated and with possibly observable side-effects. Updated the answer.

Comment: Evalation can make arbitrarily huge difference if the expression under `sizeof` has side effects. Like `int a[x][x], i = 0; sizeof a[i++];`. Variable `i` is supposed to get incremented.

Answer (score 7):

> My question is how exactly sizeof() behaves when passed argument is a dynamic array.

1. Well, you rather meant a "variable-length array" (VLA).
2. It behaves almost exactly the same: it returns the size of the array in bytes.

> sizeof() 'behaves like' a function and not as an operator.

Nah, it never was a function. The only thing that changes is that if used on VLAs, this operator doesn't yield a compile-time constant, otherwise it does.